# How can I click multiple items in Python Selenium with the same xpath?

Tags: python, html, css, python-3.x, selenium

I have a webpage with the following code:

```
<label data-correct="false">
    <input type="radio" ng-model="quizCtrl.state.selectedOptionForCurrentQuestion" ng-value="option" name="q0" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-empty" value="[object Object]">

    <!--option image-->
    <!---->

    <!--option text-->
    <span ng-bind-html="quizCtrl.trustAsHtml(option.text)"><p>Earned three college degrees and supported himself as a small businessman - Google values entrepreneurship.</p></span>
</label>
<label data-correct="true">
    <input type="radio" ng-model="quizCtrl.state.selectedOptionForCurrentQuestion" ng-value="option" name="q0" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-empty" value="[object Object]">

    <!--option image-->
    <!---->

    <!--option text-->
    <span ng-bind-html="quizCtrl.trustAsHtml(option.text)"><p>Has several years of work experience, and enjoys volunteering for Habitat for Humanity - Google values these character traits.</p></span>
</label>
<label data-correct="false">
    <input type="radio" ng-model="quizCtrl.state.selectedOptionForCurrentQuestion" ng-value="option" name="q0" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-empty" value="[object Object]">

    <!--option image-->
    <!---->

    <!--option text-->
    <span ng-bind-html="quizCtrl.trustAsHtml(option.text)"><p>Recently graduated from Harvard University - Google is known for hiring the best and the brightest.</p></span>
</label>
<label data-correct="false">
    <input type="radio" ng-model="quizCtrl.state.selectedOptionForCurrentQuestion" ng-value="option" name="q0" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-empty" value="[object Object]">

    <!--option image-->
    <!---->

    <!--option text-->
    <span ng-bind-html="quizCtrl.trustAsHtml(option.text)"><p>Worked as an independent contractor in different areas of the computer industry - Google values versatility.</p></span>
</label>
```

I'm creating a script that checks the `data-correct` label. And if it's true then it should click it. They all have the same xpath and tag. So How can I go about doing this?

They all have this xpath:

````
/html/body/div[3]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[1]/study-quiz/div/form/div/div[2]/ng 
 include/div[2]/div[3]/ng-include/label```
````

This is my code so far:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

elems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(
    '/html/body/div[3]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[1]/study-quiz/div/form/div/div[2]/ng-include/div[2]/div[3]/ng-include/label')

count = 0

while(count != len(elems)):
    elems = WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(
        EC.presence_of_all_elements_located(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[3]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[1]/study-quiz/div/form/div/div[2]/ng-include/div[2]/div[3]/ng-include/label'))
    elems[count].click()
    count += 1

print(f'found {count} answer')
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver_path = '' # Chromedriver executable Path
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'/home/severus/Desktop/drivers/chromedriver')
elems = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//label[@data-correct='true']") # Get all elemts where Attr data-correct='true'

for elem in elems:
    # clicks all data-correct='true' Labels.
    elem.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use "driver.find_elements_by_xpath()" function, it will return the list of elements (if present), then apply loop and perform your logic.

Comment: But how can I know if it's true or false?

Comment: element.is_selected()

Answer (score 0):

it easier using css selector,

```
# select <label> that has attribute data-correct
elems = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('label[data-correct]')

for elem in elems:
    if elem.get_attribute('data-correct') == "true":
        elem.click()
    else:
        print("false")
```

Comment: This returns ```AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'click'```

Comment: `elem` is not `list` did you write it correctly and not `elems` with `s` ?